# How to turn a Unique Constraint into a Primary key in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has a `primary key` on some columns, and another `unique constraint` on another column.

I dropped the old primary key, and now want to make the existing unique constraint the new primary key of the table, *without dropping/rebuilding it* from scratch.

The situation right now is like this:

```
Indexes:
    "t_review_routing_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id)
```

When I run:

```
ALTER TABLE t_review_routing ADD PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX t_review_routing_id_key;
```

It says:

```
ERROR:  index "t_review_routing_id_key" is already associated with a constraint
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE t_review_routing ADD PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX t_r...
```

I also tried `ALTER TABLE t_review_routing ADD CONSTRAINT t_review_routing_id_pkey PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX t_review_routing_id_key;`, same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: drop the constraint.

Comment: Were you able to drop the original primary key?

Comment: @DanBracuk Isn't dropping and recreating it a heavy operation? I am trying to use the already-built index that is there.

Comment: What difference does it make?  It's not a regular event, is it?

Answer (score 6):

You can drop your already existing constraint before creating the new one, but *dropping the constraint will make the index disappear too.*

But, you can create a new index `CONCURRENTLY` ([example from the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html#AEN67197)):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY dist_id_temp_idx ON distributors (dist_id);
ALTER TABLE distributors DROP CONSTRAINT distributors_pkey,
    ADD CONSTRAINT distributors_pkey PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX dist_id_temp_idx;
```

This method is explicitly mentioned at the docs of `ALTER TABLE ... ADD table_constraint_using_index`.

Comment: This is a pretty heavy operation. The docs bring it as an example for refreshing an index without blocking the table.
I am looking for a way to use the already existing index without having to recreate a new one

Comment: @AliMoosavi as your error message suggests, you can do that only if that index does not belongs to a constraint already. This is a decent workaround, i think.

Comment: @pozs Should I drop the temporary index afterwards?

Comment: Also, this question is 10 years old. Maybe it works already? Although, I am on CockroachDB.